# Function Not Utilizing Error Conditions Properly

Tags: c, function, error-handling

Im making a function for a basic program yet when I call it it does not utilize the do trap loop error conditions properly.

im calling it in the program like so....

```
for (x = 0; x < num_grades; x++)
{
                
                
     do
     {
      get_grade(grade, x, name);

      if (grade < 0 || grade > 100)
          printf ("*** Invalid entry. Grade must be 0 to 100.\n");

      } while (grade < 0 || grade > 100);
```

The function itself looks like this...

```
int get_grade (int grade, int i, char name[][25]) // A function to get grades //
{
    char c;
    int grade_get;
            
        printf ("Enter grade #%i for %s: ", i+1, name[i] );
        scanf  ("%i", &grade);
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

    return grade_get;

}
```

I have prototyped it like so...

```
int get_grade (int, int, char [][25]);
```

I tried putting the error conditions in the function but it doesn't work with the for loop properly unless I did it wrong.

I know the code is inefficient but this is for a college class so we are only allowed to use what we learned and this is about the extent we learned. We haven't learned pointers or strcopy or anything like that so while it may be basic I don't have a choice :/

Thank you for your time and I appreciate any and all help :)

Comment: In C parameters are passed by value, so changing `grade` inside the function changes a copy, not the original. You should assign the return value from `get_grade()`, like `grade = get_grade();`. You also read into the `grade` variable but return the uninitialized `grade_get`. Remove the grade parameter, and read into `grade_get`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for your help! I appreciate it however I'm kind of lost on what you mean as im not the best with coding terms. What would that look like in the context of my code as to what would go where?  If you could explain it to me like you would a child that goes a long way for me lol.

Comment: You either need to use `int get_grade (int *grade, int i, char name[][25]) { … }` and call `get_grade(&grade, i, name)` (and then you either use the return value to return success/failure or perhaps make the return type `void` instead of `int`), or you use `int get_grade (int i, char name[][25])` and then call `grade = get_grade(i, name);`.  Though, since you don't really use the array properties of `name` in the function, it would be simpler to have `const char *name` in the prototype and pass `name[i]` to the function.  You still need to pass `i` to the function since you use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sounds good thanks for the help most of it is working however im not sure how to make the printf statement properly display the name stored in the name array. Any ideas? Im in the home stretch so thank you very much lol.

Comment: If you're passing `name[i]` to the function (so the prototype has `char *name`), then `printf("%s", name)` prints the name.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `grade_get` variable is not initialized so the function returns an undefined value.
2. `grade` either has to be a pointer or you can return the value (like I did)
3. Prefer only passing the the values (one name) instead of all names.  If you don't need `i` in the function it would be even cleaner.
4. `getchar()` returns an int so change type of `c` to `int`.
5. Program was incomplete so had to add the missing parts to get it to compile.
6. Moved validation logic to `get_grade()`.  This simplifies `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_grade (int i, const char *name) {
    int grade;

    for(;;) {
        printf ("Enter grade #%i for %s: ", i+1, name);
        scanf  ("%i", &grade);
        int c;
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
        if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
             return grade;
        printf ("*** Invalid entry. Grade must be 0 to 100.\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    const char names[][25] = {
        "bob",
        "bjork",
        "jane"
    };
    for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeof(names) / sizeof(*names); x++) {
         int grade = get_grade(x, names[x]);
    }
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
Enter grade #1 for bob: -1
*** Invalid entry. Grade must be 0 to 100.
Enter grade #1 for bob: 0
Enter grade #2 for bjork: 101
*** Invalid entry. Grade must be 0 to 100.
Enter grade #2 for bjork: 100
Enter grade #3 for jane: 42
```